# Python3 - Chrome weird url decode with urllib.parse.parse_qs()

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, decode, python-3.4

When I submit a form inside a Browser (Chrome), I get the umlauts "öäü" back encoded as `%F6%E4%FC` (I was using a POST request [Form submit] and got that from the protocol body), although if I do the same inside Python, I get `%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC`.

The Problem is now that if I unquote the Python encoding, it works perfectly (as expected), but the encoded from the Browser fails.

Does someone know why? Or at least explain it me? Running Python **3.4** on Ubuntu.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote('öäü')
'%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC'
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs('v=' + _)
{'v': ['öäü']}
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs('v=' + '%F6%E4%FC') # That encoded String from the Browser
{'v': ['���']}
```

Comment: Yes! o-o But why Latin-1?

Comment: `hex 'E4'  == ä`, `hex F6 == ö`, `hex 'FC' == ü`, they are the iso latin-1 numeric values of those chars http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string from your browser is latin-1 encoded, urllib.parse is using utf-8, if you use latin-1 as the encoding you get the same output using urllib.parse.quote:

```
In [32]: urllib.parse.quote('öäü',encoding="latin-1")
Out[32]: '%F6%E4%FC'
```

`"FC"` and the other hex values are ISO Latin 1 numeric values for the characters:

```
In [34]: "\xFC"
Out[34]: 'ü'
In [38]: "\xF6"
Out[38]: 'ö'
```

To get the correct output you need to specify the correct encoding:

```
In [40]: urllib.parse.parse_qs('v=' + '%F6%E4%FC',encoding="latin-1")
Out[40]: {'v': ['öäü']}
```

There is a  list of the utf-8 code points from  U+0000 to U+00FF [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/), the ISO Latin 1 code are [here](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html)